# Another Popen stdin.write vs communicate question

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

while using the `subprocess` module for various things, I still struggle when it comes to proper handling of `Popen` input.

communicate example

```
with subprocess.Popen(
    ['cat', '-'] 
    , text=True
    , stdin=subprocess.PIPE
) as sub:
    sub.communicate(''.join(str(i) for i in range(10)))

# returns 0123456789
```

Discouraged use of `stdin.write`, but works. (see warning under https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdin)

```
with subprocess.Popen(
    ['cat', '-'] 
    , text=True
    , stdin=subprocess.PIPE
) as sub:
    for i in range(10):
        sub.stdin.write(str(i))

# returns 0123456789
```

This variation with using `communicate` multiple times however does not work.

```
with subprocess.Popen(
    ['cat', '-'] 
    , text=True
    , stdin=subprocess.PIPE
) as sub:
    for i in range(10):
        sub.communicate(f'{i}')

# crashes after 1.st iteration with
# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

I can see, why it does not work. But what is then the correct/pythonic way to send data to `subprocess.Popen`? The data I'm dealing with are rather large (think tens of GB) and I prefer to generate and process them on the fly.

Thanks

Comment: Related: [Communicating multiple times with a subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3453345/11082165), [Communicate multiple times with a process without breaking the pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3065060/11082165)

Comment: THX for the links, I've went through those. They seem to send me to the `stdin.write` route. But I'm hoping that there is something better which I'm not aware of.